# Has anyone compared or have any benchmarks of Bond vs JIL for JSON parsing?

Tags: json, parsing, jil, bond

[BOND](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond)
is a cross-platform framework for working with schematized data. It supports cross-language de/serialization and powerful generic mechanisms for efficiently manipulating data. Bond is broadly used at Microsoft in high scale services.

it's written in Haskell and, apparently, faster than protobuf

[JIL](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil) A fast JSON (de)serializer, built on Sigil with a number of somewhat crazy optimization tricks.

it's written using IL and, apparently, faster than protobuf

But I've not seen *anyone* yet compare the two, and I can't currently run benchmarks  on a dev environment.

Comment: JIL does not come close to protobuf.
See the various payload pattern tests here: http://aumcode.github.io/serbench/

Comment: We are planning to add BOND and Avro. But they are very specialized, it is gard to call them "transparent general-purpose" solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Bond was recently added to this [JSON serializer benchmark blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/LeonidGaneline/archive/2015/05/06/serializers-in-.net.-v.2.aspx):

[image: json benchmark]

But note the warning:

> There is no such thing as the “best serializer”. If you invest time in optimizing code, the loser will be winner. If you change the test data, the winner would not be winner anymore.

Comment: we have replaced this with THIS: http://aumcode.github.io/serbench/  the results are way more accurate. Also, according to different payload patterns JIL is not the fastest JSON serializer and certainly it does not come close to Protobuf.  Use SERBENCH, the majority of other benchmarks are fiction fabricated to see good numbers